# Websocket read/write at same the time possible?

Tags: swift, websocket, starscream

Is it possible that a websocket client connection, while receiving larger number of data chunks, can send data to server at the same time?

Comment: It actually depends if the websocket-receive / send functions are blocking, if not it should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just discovered that the callback functions are blocking. That leads to solution.